# Отнюдь непотопляемый / не потопляемый

Tags: орфография

Как я понимаю, слово *непотопляемый* – это то, которое не пишется без *не-*, и надо, следовательно, нисать 1-й вариант. Так?

`1. Титаник, думали, – отнюдь непотопляемый и непобедимый корабль, но, очевидно, облажались.`

`2. Титаник, думали, – отнюдь не потопляемый и непобедимый корабль, но, очевидно, облажались.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильно (стилизованный вариант с  той же семантикой):

*Титаник, думали, стопрцентно **непотопляемый корабль**, но, видать, облажались.*

**НЕПОТОПЛЯЕМЫЙ**, -ая, -ое. 1. Обладающий непотопляемостью (о судне). 2. Способный сохранять свой статус при изменении ситуации. Н. министр.

Слова ***"потопляемый"*** нет в словаре.

**Тире** не ставится: вводное предложение (***думали***) между подлежащим и сказуемым.